# Interop.Excel.Range vs dynamic

Tags: c#, excel, range

When I had tried to set up a number format for a range of cells in an excel file, I found a quite strange behavior.
There are two examples of code:

```
// First example uses the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range interface.
void SetupFormat(Range range)
{
    range.NumberFormat = "0" + CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator + "00%";
}

// Second one uses a dynamic.
void SetupFormat(dynamic range)
{
    range.NumberFormat = "0" + CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator + "00%";
}
```

When I use the first method I get numbers like 012%, when I use the second method I get numbers like 12,34% (as expected).
First method is work fine when I use period in the number format. Does anybody know why that methods have different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that *dynamic* call to *NumberFormat* dispatches to *NumberFormatLocal* property. All data passed in excel API should be encoded in excel-invariant culture (locale 1033, [explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms268748(v=vs.100).aspx)). So you must pass all formats in 1033 locale and data in such locale too.
If you replace static *NumberFormat* with *NumberFormatLocal* it will be ok.